# Do something after div loads with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

i have some problem with my jquery. I need to remove first two elements from some list after specify div loads. When document is ready I didn't have this div in my DOM, it's appending after some click action. So, what i need to do is make function which this specify div will be adding to my DOM. This is my code, thx for help.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if ($('.sv_flex_slider .slides').find('li').size() > 3) {
        $('#fancybox-thumbs').load(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#fancybox-thumbs ul').find('li').eq(1).remove();
                $('#fancybox-thumbs ul').find('li').eq(2).remove();    
            },200);
        })
    }
},200);
```

Comment: Where is the click action that loads the content?

Comment: By what do you mean after the element is loaded? If it's a regular div, span etc. that you append, that's done syncronously, and there is no load event triggered for that? Also the `load()` function used this way is deprecated, and `.on('load', function() { ... })` is now reccomended, but that's not the reason for this not working btw.

Comment: in a completely different place, she calls the fancybox window with these miniatures

Comment: Is there any reason you can't modify the listener for the click, or add a separate listener? If not, then you could use DOM mutation events (complex) or use setInterval to periodically check for the existance of the element.

Comment: @adeneo I click on the picture, appears to me fancybox with miniatures, but the block is added dynamically at the beginning is not in the DOM

Comment: Yes, I get it, but there is no load even fired for that, you'll have to trigger a custom event when loading the content, or place the code after the append function when the element exists, the load event will not help you here etc.

Comment: hmm, that's some kind of idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a trigger when the div is created. Like this:

```
$('#some_element').on('click', function () {
    var $element = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'newDiv');
    $element.trigger('created');    
});
```

Then you can listen to that:

```
$('body').on('created', '#newDiv'....
```